# Java tomcat6 OOM, massive amount of com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl instances

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've got a Java web application which runs fine for about 2 days. After that it hangs with OOM heap space errors.

A thread dump gives the following information about the heap:

> Heap  par new generation   total 38336K, used 38181K [0x00000000d5a00000, 0x00000000d8390000, 0x00000000d8390000)
>   eden space 34112K, 100% used [0x00000000d5a00000, 0x00000000d7b50000, 0x00000000d7b50000)
>   from space 4224K,  96% used [0x00000000d7b50000, 0x00000000d7f49628, 0x00000000d7f70000)
>   to   space 4224K,   0% used [0x00000000d7f70000, 0x00000000d7f70000, 0x00000000d8390000) 
>   concurrent mark-sweep generation total 481728K, used 481727K [0x00000000d8390000, 0x00000000f5a00000, 0x00000000f5a00000) 
>   concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 38172K, used 22900K [0x00000000f5a00000, 0x00000000f7f47000, 0x0000000100000000)

I made a heapdump which I read with VisualVM. This shows me that there is a massive amount (1.2 million) of StatementImpl instances which take up a lot of memory.

Some information about the application:

- 16 sql connections
- 32 insert statements per second
- About 200 procedure calls per second

All inserts and procedure calls go divided over those 16 connections. I never close the connections, since I keep using them. I'm 100% sure I close all Statements and PreparedStatements.

What could be the cause of the large amount of StatementImpl instances?

Comment: You could try setting "dontTrackOpenResources=true" on your JDBC URL to see if it makes a difference. If it does, then there's either a bug in the driver or you are not closing a statement somewhere. c.f. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Gonna try that, thanks. I'm using Connector/J 5.1.27 driver.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jess. Found out that I forgot a "finally" block for closing a statement.